# Creating a color picker

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to add a color picker to my website, so people can change the color of the background of the page. I would like to have a square, with all the possible colors in it, like below. When someone clicks on a pixel, it's color is stored as a variable.

[image: Color picker]

What programming language should I use for this? Any tips greatly appreciated.

Comment: why dont you use any existing jquery/javascript colorpicker instead of reinventing a wheel

Comment: Google is your best friend: **jQuery color pickers** or **HTML color pickers**  should return many results for you to look at.

Comment: It might be a fun little project to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tons of such tools available online. But for the sake of a programming challenge, I'll give you some guidelines/ideas if you (or someone else reading this) still decide to build it yourself.

---

You can use JavaScript and HTML canvas.

The first step is getting the color image on the canvas, you can either draw the existing image onto it, or build it programmatically - it doesn't matter which you choose. Key for this step: [drawImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)

The next step is adding an event listener on the canvas, and using the image data to recognize the RGB(A) values of the clicked pixel. Key for this step: [getImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData)

Finally, you use that RGB(A) values and assign it to the background color.